# Alert Action Not Showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have my notification, but for some reason it still doesnt come up as an alert view.

Here it is :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (notification) {
        notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.alertBody = @"Notification";
        notification.alertAction = @"View";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
```

Comment: Do you exit your app within 5 seconds of it launching? The alert will only show if you're not within the app.

Comment: Yes i did it came up as a banner

Comment: Oh, well, then you just have to set it up in the settings of your device to show an alert instead of a banner.

Comment: Its in the simulator, no settings for notificcations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view your local notification as a UIAlertView and not a banner, you'll have to test your app on an actual device and change your app's notification 'Alert Style' in Settings. Since, as you said, there is no 'Notifications' option in the simulator's Settings, it will always default to a banner.